# How can I set a scheduled boot for a MacBook running Windows?

Tags: windows, bootcamp, startup, macos

I have a MacBook Air running OSX Big Sur along with a Boot Camp installation of Windows 10.  If I boot into OSX and go to *System Preferences -> Battery -> Schedule*, I can set a time each day for the MacBook to turn on.

If I shutdown the MacBook while running OSX, then the MacBook will properly boot back up at the scheduled time.  Yay! (It boots to Windows by default, which is fine.)

HOWEVER, if I shutdown the MacBook while running Windows, the MacBook DOES NOT boot at the scheduled time.

My guess is that the MacBook isn't seeing the trigger to automatically boot since that setting is defined in OSX and the laptop isn't getting far enough to query OSX after running Windows.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load custom code to do this. We use BootRunner to do this.

- https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/boot-runner/

It’s amazing and the support is excellent.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your laptop isn't running OSX and Windows at the same time. Windows is installed as a separate partition, not a virtual machine. When you boot into Windows, there is no OSX to 'query'. If Windows has these features, I would imagine you would enable them in Windows.